# Android Studio Drag and Drop Multiple Objects Simultaneously

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, multi-touch

I am making a racing game with 2 cars, each of which to be controlled by a different player on the same device. I used the OnTouchEvent method to move the cars by drag and drop. I can't test the code on my laptop because my laptop can't do multi-touch and only allows me to control one car at  a time (I only have the emulator from Android Studio, and no physical Android device). So what I currently know is that this code allows the cars to be moved one at a time. I was wondering if my code actually makes it so that the cars can be moved at the same time (which is what I want)or if they can only be moved one at a time:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            // press down
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // conditionals check which car is tapped on
                if (car.getCollisionShape().contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                    car.setActionDown(true);
                } else if (car2.getCollisionShape().contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                    car2.setActionDown(true);
                }
                break;
            // finger moved along screen
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // moves the cars horizontally where the fingers are moved
                if(car.getActionDown()) {
                    car.setPosition(event.getX(), car.y, true);
                } else if (car2.getActionDown()) {
                    car2.setPosition(event.getX(), car2.y, true);
                }
                break;
            // finger released
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // conditionals check which car is tapped on
                if (car.getCollisionShape().contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                    car.setActionDown(false);
                } else if (car2.getCollisionShape().contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                    car2.setActionDown(false);
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Inside the ACTION_DOWN, a car's boolean, which signals if the car is currently being hold down or not, becomes true.
Inside, the ACTION_MOVE, the car's location is shifted to wherever the event.getX() and event.getY() are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code doesn't seem to be designed properly for handling multi-touch operations. To make multi-touch work, `pointer-IDs` are required, which can be obtained by using [MotionEvent.getPointerId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getPointerId(int)).

Steps to handle multi-touch gestures are roughly outlined as follows.

1. Get pointer-ID in `ACTION_DOWN` and map the ID to the car instance according to hit test result.
2. And in subsequent actions (`ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP`), determine for which car the MotionEvent is targeted, based on the pointer-ID. And then apply changes to the relevant car instance.

See [the official training documentation for handling multi-touch gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi).

By the way, emulator has a little function to simulate multi-touch by mouse (mainly for testing pinch and spread gestures). You may be able to utilize it for testing your app. See `Pinch and spread` section in [this table](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#navigate) to know how to use it.